# Internet not working on Ubunto18.04 with Virtualbox on Windows

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox, network-manager, ethernet

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
#iface enp0s3 inet loopback
```

The command to restart hangs saying this:
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service

Comment: Why aren't you using Network Manager? Is this a server? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Also, the loopback entries for lo must not be removed.

Comment: I did the above steps. Now I can see the three computer symbol to the top-right. But, of the 3 computer symbol, only one is lit with white X symbol. Still no internet.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ip addr show` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Comment these lines-

## auto enp0s3

## iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

and un-comment below lines

## auto lo

## iface lo inet loopback

and restart network service

## systemctl restart network-manager

hope this should work for you. as your system have network manager and network manager don't manage this file-

/etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I did the above steps. Now I can see the three computer symbol to the top-right. But, of the 3 computer symbol, only one is lit with white X symbol. Still no internet.

Comment: I rebooted the virtual machine. Now all three computers in the top-right symbol are seen in white. But, still not internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help.
Along with the above issue, this too was happening:
[Internet is working, but Firefox 67 browser cannot connect after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145311/internet-is-working-but-firefox-67-browser-cannot-connect-after-update)